# Pgxpool returns "pool closed" error on Scan

Tags: go, pgx

I'm trying to implement pgxpool in a new go app. I keep getting a "pool closed" error after attempting a scan into a struct.

The pgx logger into gives me this after connecting. I thought the pgxpool was meant to remain open.

> {"level":"info","msg":"closed connection","pid":5499,"time":"2022-02-24T16:36:33+10:30"}

Here is my router code

```
func router() http.Handler {

    var err error

    config, err := pgxpool.ParseConfig(os.Getenv("DATABASE_URL"))

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }

    log.Println(os.Getenv("DATABASE_URL"))

    logrusLogger := &logrus.Logger{
        Out:          os.Stderr,
        Formatter:    new(logrus.JSONFormatter),
        Hooks:        make(logrus.LevelHooks),
        Level:        logrus.InfoLevel,
        ExitFunc:     os.Exit,
        ReportCaller: false,
    }

    config.ConnConfig.Logger = NewLogger(logrusLogger)

    db, err := pgxpool.ConnectConfig(context.Background(), config)

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }

    defer db.Close()

--- minio connection

rs := newAppResource(db, mc)
```

Then, in a helper file I setup the resource

```
type appResource struct {
   db *pgxpool.Pool
   mc *minio.Client
}

// newAppResource function to pass global var
func newAppResource(db *pgxpool.Pool, mc *minio.Client) *appResource {
    return &appResource{
        db: db,
        mc: mc,
    }
}
```

There "pool closed" error occurs at the end of this code

```
func (rs *appResource) login(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

    var user User
    var login Login

    d := json.NewDecoder(r.Body)
    d.DisallowUnknownFields() // catch unwanted fields

    err := d.Decode(&login)
    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusBadRequest)
        return
    }

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("can't decode JSON", err)
    }

    if login.Email == "" {
        log.Println("empty email")
        return
    }

    log.Println(login.Email)

    log.Println(login.Password)

    if login.Password == "" {
        log.Println("empty password")
        return
    }

    // optional extra check
    if d.More() {
        http.Error(w, "extraneous data after JSON object", http.StatusBadRequest)
        return
    }

    sqlStatement := "SELECT user_id, password FROM users WHERE active = 'true' AND email = ?"

    row := rs.db.QueryRow(context.Background(), sqlStatement, login.Email)

    err = row.Scan(&user.UserId, &user.Password)

    if err == sql.ErrNoRows {
        log.Println("user not found")
        http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusUnauthorized)
        return
    }

    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
        http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
        return
    }
```

Comment: You will need to show us how `rs.db` is set. Ideally provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). My guess would be that you use `db` after `router()` has returned (and the `defer` has closed it).

Comment: I edited my question to show the resource setup. You are right, it looks like the router function closes the connection after it returns. Perhaps I need to setup my connections and resource in main which won't return. This same code worked fine using database/sql.

Comment: Just remove the `defer db.Close()` (you can close it as part of clean shutdown if needed - as [the docs](https://pkg.go.dev/database/sql#Open) say "It is rarely necessary to close a DB.")

Comment: Please write that up as an answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears that you are doing something like the following:

```golang
func router() http.Handler {
   db, err := pgxpool.ConnectConfig(context.Background(), config)
   if err != nil {
       log.Fatalln(err)
   }
   defer db.Close()

   return appResource{db: db}
}
```

The issue with this is that the `defer db.Close()` runs when the function `router()` ends and this is before the returned `pgxPool.Pool` is actually used (the `http.Handler` returned will be used later when http requests are processed). Attempting to use a closed `pgxPool.Pool` results in the error you are seeing.

The simplest solution is to simply remove the `defer db.Close()` however you might also consider calling `db.Close()` as part of a clean shutdown process (it needs to remain open as long as you are handling requests).

You are using `pgxpool` which does differ from the standard library; however I believe that the advice given in the [standard library docs](https://pkg.go.dev/database/sql#Open) applies here:

> It is rarely necessary to close a DB.